# $\lim_{R\to\infty} R^{-n} \mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,R): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) = 0$ if $I_s(\mu) < \infty$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dimension-theory-analysis

$\mathcal M(\Bbb R^n)$ denotes the set of all Borel measures $\mu$ on $\Bbb R^n$ with $0 < \mu(\Bbb R^n) < \infty$ and compact support $\operatorname{spt}\mu \subset \Bbb R^n$.

> Suppose $\mu\in \mathcal M(\Bbb R^n)$ and $I_s(\mu) = \gamma(n,s)\int |\hat\mu(x)|^2 |x|^{s-n}\, dx < \infty$. Then, $$|\hat\mu(x)|\le |x|^{-s/2}$$
> for 'most' $x$ with large norm. Here, 'most' simply means what is needed in order that the above integral would be finite. For example, we must have $$\lim_{R\to\infty} R^{-n} \mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,R): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) = 0$$

---

I am trying to see why $\lim_{R\to\infty} R^{-n} \mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,R): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) = 0$ in this case. By definition, $$\lim_{R\to\infty} R^{-n} \mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,R): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) = 0$$
means that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $R_\epsilon > 0$ such that $$R\ge R_\epsilon \implies |R^{-n} \mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,R): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) | < \epsilon$$
Suppose the negation is true, i.e., there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $R > 0$, there exists $r \ge R$ such that $$\mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,r): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) \ge \epsilon r^n$$
which implies $$\mathcal L^n(\{x\in B(0,r): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}) \ge \epsilon R^n$$

How should I proceed? Thank you!

---

Note: $\mathcal L^n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

---

Reference: *Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension* by Pertti Mattila.

Comment: Maybe this helps: $A_R:=\{|x|<R:|\hat{\mu}(x)|>|x|^{-s/2}\}=\{|x|<R:|\hat{\mu}(x)|^2>|x|^{-s}\}$

$$\int_{A_R}|\hat{\mu}(x)|^2 |x|^{s-n}dx>\int_{A_R}|x|^{-n}\,dx>R^{-n}|A_R|$$

Comment: Notice that the statement is about a necessary condition for convergence of $I_s(\mu)$. The goal is to control the size (measure) of of the "bad" set $A_R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$A_R:=\{x\in B(0,R): |\hat\mu(x)| > |x|^{-s/2}\}$$
and let $$D_R:=A_R \setminus B(0,\sqrt{R})\,.$$
Then for all $x \in D_R$, we have
$R^{-n} \le |x|^{-n} \le  |\hat\mu(x)|^2 |x|^{s-n}\,,$
so
$$R^{-n}  \mathcal L^n(D_R) \le \int_{D_R}      |\hat\mu(x)|^2 |x|^{s-n}\, dx \le \int_{ \Bbb R^n}
|\hat\mu(x)|^2 |x|^{s-n} {\bf 1}_{\{|x|\ge \sqrt{R}\}} \,dx \to 0$$
as $R \to \infty$ by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.
Finally,
$$R^{-n}  \mathcal L^n(A_R) \le R^{-n}  \mathcal L^n(D_R) +R^{-n}  \mathcal L^n(B(0,\sqrt{R})) \to 0 \quad \text{as} \;\:  R \to \infty \,.$$

Comment: (+1)  That was a very simple and ingenious trick.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you for pointing me to this problem. As you can see, this is a small modification of your comment above. These energy integrals were crucial in one of my all time favorite papers,  Peres, Yuval, and Wilhelm Schlag. "Smoothness of projections, Bernoulli convolutions, and the dimension of exceptions." Duke Mathematical Journal 102, no. 2 (2000): 193-251.

Comment: Hi Yuval, [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625737/121671) is recent problem retaliated to this one and I thought that it might be interesting.