# Prove or disprove: an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a union of disjoint open balls

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following result.

> Prove or disprove: every open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a union of countably many disjoint open balls $B_r (x)$, where we allow $r = \infty$.

The use of "disjoint" open balls is throwing me off. If $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set, then for every $u \in U$, I can find an open ball $B_{r_u} (u) \subset U$. Then $U = \bigcup\limits_{u \in U} B_{r_u} (u)$, and I've written $U$ as a union of disjoint open balls. I'm not sure how to "shrink" the radii of the open balls. I could perhaps add a condition that the radii become progressively decreasing, e.g., I start with some radius $r$, then take $\frac{r}{2}$, then $\frac{r}{3}$, and so forth.

I'd appreciate some help on how to show this.

Comment: An open rectangle cannot be written as a disjoint union of open balls by connectedness.

Comment: As an immediate consequence of Yuval's answer and the comment by @KaviRamaMurthy , the claim is false for all connected open sets.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Well, it is true for open balls.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks for correcting me. I was wrong indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a countable collection $\{B_j\}_{j \ge 1}$ of disjoint open balls in the  the open unit square $Q=(0,1)^2$. At most 4 of the points on the boundary of $B_1$ are outside $Q$, and none of the remaining balls $B_2, B_3, \ldots$ can cover any point of $\partial B_1$. Thus
$\{B_j\}_{j \ge 1}$ cannot cover $Q$.

Comment: It seems that the remaining balls can't even cover a single point of $\del B_1$. If you agree, I think modifying the answer in this way would make it clearer.

Comment: Just as a complement: your answer actually proves the claim is false for any connected open set, since open sets always contain rectangles $(u, u + \varepsilon)^2$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough.

Comment: Obviously, a duplicate question.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks, corrected

Comment: @MatheusAndrade: that generalization doesn't follow by this argument, because the balls would not then be constrained to lie inside the rectangle. And indeed, a ball itself can be covered by a countable collection of (one) open ball.

Comment: @GregMartin good point, thanks for correcting me. I was a bit too hasty there.

Comment: @YuvalPeres: Hi Yuval, this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460125/121671) may be of interest to you. I thought it was trivial but there may be a trick that I cannot see.